# Specify main class Spring-Boot command line

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use maven plugin to set the main class like this :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <mainClass>com.myapp.main.MainClass</mainClass>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

But sometimes I want run my app with another main class. What is the command line arguments to do this?

```
java -jar myapp-1.0.jar ...
```

Thx

Comment: +1. I have the same question (I settled for writing my own "master" Main class which looks at the first argument and then dispatches somewhere else, so that you can get a nice command line without full class names and weird -D stuff, but would be good to know when you want to run any classes that you did not think of ahead of time).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple runnable classes inside JAR, how to run them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976514/multiple-runnable-classes-inside-jar-how-to-run-them)

Comment: Vinay Lodha, no it's not working: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/BeansException`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a [launcher for that in Spring Boot already](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features). You need to build the jar with that as the Main-Class ([by setting the `layout` in the build config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#layout)).

Comment: And you want to set the layout to "ZIP" to get the PropertyLauncher.

Comment: I know this is a old post but still had a question. So do you need to build 2 different jars with different mains? or can it be specified as a command line parameter in the same jar?

Comment: Did you see this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features?

Answer (score 51):

Following command will do the trick:

```
java -cp my-app.jar -Dloader.main=myApplicationClass org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.PropertiesLauncher
```

Comment: IMO this is the best solution for those that don't want to mess w/ their maven configs.

Comment: Works great, thanks - note for others that myApplicationClass would be your package qualified class, and you just don't touch the spring package at the end :).

Comment: Best solution! also little bit of explenation about  the PropertiesLauncher will be nice

Comment: Hi, this isn't working for me, I'm launching:

 java -cp .\myjar.jar -Dloader.main=com.mypackage.MyMain org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

and I get: 

Error: Could not find or load main class .main=com.mypackage.MyMain

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Executing from Windows PowerShell I needed this format (with the quotes):

`java -cp .\myjarfile.jar -D"loader.main=com.app.etc.FullyQualifiedMainClass" org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher`

To clarify the accepted answer: You can directly modify the loader.main property in the jar's META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file, if you're ok with a more static solution.

Answer (score 1):

For WAR files:

```
java -cp salamander-1.0.0.war -Dloader.path=WEB-INF/classes,WEB-INF/lib -Dloader.main=com.frog.katak.MyMainClass org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```