# Running a jar file having multiple main classes using command line

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, executable-jar, maven-assembly-plugin

Have added multiple main classes in jar using following code in pom.xml as follows

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>indexer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <id>build-first</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.test1</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <finalName>first-runnable</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <id>build-second</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer
                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.test2</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <finalName>second-runnable</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But unable to run the jar file successfully from command line. Tried using the command line as
**java -jar indexer-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.test1**
but get **no main manifest attribute, in indexer-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar**

Could anyone please guide how to run the main classes from commandline using this jar.

Thanks

Comment: I think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976514/multiple-runnable-classes-inside-jar-how-to-run-them

Comment: Thanks bmavus. I cant use the java -cp command specified as solution there as there are many jar files in the classpath which will have to be given in commandline. Previously if only one main class file in jar was there could run it using  java -jar indexer-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar. Looking for some command which is similar.

Comment: I am not sure and did not try it befor but have you ever tried something like java -cp myjar.jar <packageName>.MyClass

Comment: Yes.Get  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext

Answer (score 1):

You should run produced artifact (first-runnable, second-runnable) instead of original one.
If you use 'finalName' tag then original artifact will not be modified and new jar will be created as described in [plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#finalName)

Run

```
java -jar first-runnable.jar com.test1
```

or

```
java -jar second-runnable.jar com.test1
```