# jar-with-dependencies + Multiple mainClass classes?

Tags: pom.xml, executable-jar

I know how to create a `myapp-with-dependencies.jar` with a single `mainClass`.

But I want to create `myapp-with-dependencies.jar` with support for different main classes at runtime. Running the different classes shoudl be as simple as this:

```
java -jar myapp-with-dependencies.jar com.myapp.MyApp1
java -jar myapp-with-dependencies.jar com.myapp.MyApp2
```

I believe with a thin jar you can do this, but then you have to specify `--classpath` which I don't want to do (it complicates my deployment script).

Is this possible? If not, what's the next best thing (besides running it like a thin jar, or [creating separate jars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743774/running-a-jar-file-having-multiple-main-classes-using-command-line)). And maybe an explanation of why this is impossible would be beneficial for me and others reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's perfectly fine for me to [use a classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976548/714112) where the fat jar contains everything:

```
java -cp myapp-with-dependencies.jar com.myapp.MyApp1
java -cp myapp-with-dependencies.jar com.myapp.MyApp2
```