# How to create a executable jar with a particular class in a project in netbeans

Tags: java, javafx, jar, path, executable-jar

This is my first question on stack overflow.
[Please have a look at this first, please!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hTw5.jpg)

I am creating an executable jar file by clicking on the button surrounded with grey color. The problem is that the exxcution of the application always starts from the "PersonalAssistant.java".
  I want my application to begin its execution from "App.java" which also contains a main() method.

So, basically the jar file which I want should begin its execution from App.java class which has a main method.

I don't know how to change the path or execution class for jar.
Please help me!!!! I'm stuck with this silly problem. But I want a solution for this.

I'm using Windows10 with Netbeans 8.2 IDE

Comment: Can't you set `App.java` to be the Main?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [reconfigure your IDE](https://www.wikihow.com/Generate-JAR-File-in-Netbeans) and rebuild the executable jar specifying which class you want to use as the executable.

in your IDE add `java -cp myjar.jar App`
 to your compile command

[this might also help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976514/multiple-runnable-classes-inside-jar-how-to-run-them)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Look at the picture above. Right-click on your project and select `Properties`. Select `Run`. Look for the `Application Class` field. In my example, I have `javafxapplication211.Main`. This structure is `projectName.MainClass`. You should just need to change the `MainClass` part to the class you want to start your project. For example, if `Main.java` was starting my app and I wanted to change it to `App.java`. I would change `javafxapplication211.Main` to `javafxapplication211.App`.

If you hit <kbd>Browse</kbd>, it will give you a list of available classes that can start the application.