# Adding jgit as a gradle dependency prevent my main class from being loader

Tags: java, gradle, jgit

2 hours ago, I ws working a java (gradle) project which needed jgit. I aded it in my build.gradle, ran ./gradlew build, and tried to java -jar the build output.
It does not work anymore, but removing the dependency makes it work again. Note that it compile without errors.
Here is my build.gradle if it can help.
https://gist.github.com/Fungie2134/cb81cd1bd7d767d4d1f5d6317e71665d

Comment: Add Gradle error when you sync the Gradle.

Comment: There is no errors at all... That the problem. (Unless the "Error: Could not find or load main class main.Launcher" one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The way I was making my fat jar was wrong. Using this

```
configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
```

with this kind of libraries happens to prevent the .jar creation to be done correctly. The solution was to use [Shadow](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/#getting_started) . Now the jar creation is done by ./gradlew shadowJar and the jar is named Launcher-all.jar

Answer (score 1):

you might be lacking the repository configuration for [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/5.0.2.201807311906-r):

```
repositories {
    jcenter()

    // add this one:
    mavenCentral()

    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

please add further details (relevant error logs), in case this should not answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But unfortunately it did not work. But when using the Eclipse or Intellij compiler, no issues. Here is the only error I got : https://gist.github.com/Fungie2134/e7457d57356631de105cb8b2f172c2d5

Comment: @AAng23 please add the log from the console; else this is guessing around.

Comment: I have just added the only ones I got here : https://gist.github.com/Fungie2134/e7457d57356631de105cb8b2f172c2d5 
There is no said error unless the java -jar one.

Comment: @AAng23 this answer explains how such launcher class should look alike:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532803/549372

Comment: It is already like this one (https://gist.github.com/Fungie2134/3b2e1fbaea70aaea69996e679552f329). It works fines with Eclipse's compiler, and works with gradle when the Jgit dependency is not declared.

Comment: you might not have the launcher in the expected location, which may be `src/main/{packageName}/`... `main/Launcher.class` (do not confuse the one `main` which refers to the source-set with the other `main`, which refers to a package-name).

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for you help tough.