# The jar libs\commons-compress-1.18.jar has a main class org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.Lister that does not match the declared main

Tags: java, javafx, jar, executable-jar, apache-commons-compress

I am developing a `Javafx` application and its ready for the build. In order to read and write excel files I,m using `org.apache.commons.compress` library (a `jar` file), which has a main class named `Lister` in it. Where as, my application has its own `MainApp` class file (essential for a `Javafx` application). So, while I'm building the application, the build is successful and a jar file of my application is also generated but I am getting this error :

```
The jar libs\commons-compress-1.18.jar has a main class  
org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.  
Lister that does not match the declared main org.dracul.tree.MainApp
Bundler EXE Installer skipped because of a configuration problem: Main application jar is missing.
```

This means that there are two main files inside my jar.

Secondly, when I'm running executable jar of my application, it crashes.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: How do you build your application? Do you use Maven or Gradle? Where does the error message come from? Show us the relevant part of you build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [specify main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976514/multiple-runnable-classes-inside-jar-how-to-run-them) when creating the jar, by adding class name as `MyClass`:

> ```
> java -cp myjar.jar MyClass
> ```

Comment: I was using eclipse for building my jar file. Earlier I was extracting required jar libraries into generated jar due to which I was getting subject error. Therefore, I packaged required libraries into generated jar and it worked. Link provided by you gave me the hint. Thanks a lot cheers!!!!